# Creating new datatable throws "Sytem.runtime.Interopservices.COMException"

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm creating a new datatable as shown in picture and it throws an exception:

> Sytem.runtime.Interopservices.COMException

I changed the target CPU to 32 bit, ran VS as administrator, closed and opened VS and none of them fixes it. If use the same line in a new winform project, it works fine. Is there a setting or some reference that could be causing the exception?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You must have removed the reference to System.Data because that is where the DataTable is defined.

Comment: No, I have system.data in there.New dataset works fine. Its only datatable. If you see in the code, i couldn't also do a dataset.tables.add(dt)....I have it as dataset.tables.add("dt") which is not correct...

Answer (score -1):

Solved. I had reference to an other software which has it own datatable. That reference was overriding system.data